# Use preferred terms suggests to change parameter name to what it already's named

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, code-analysis

I have a repository interface with the following member:

```
void Update(T entity, string loginName);
```

When running Code Analysis I get the following error:

> CA1726    Use preferred terms In member 'IRepository.Update(T, string)', replace the term 'loginName' in parameter name 'loginName' with the preferred alternate 'loginName'.

Am I missing something here, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Code analysis simply don't want you to use "login". The book that codeAnalysis uses as its style rules mention that you should use logon instead.

You can simply change loginName to logonName and your problem should be solved.

Comment: i don't get why you or anyone would downvote my comment, i had the exact same problem, and it solved it for me...